# The dimension of the eigenvector space of non-negative irreducible matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvector

Let $A$ be an irreducible non-negative matrix. Is it true that the eigenvectors of $A$ can span the $R^n$ ?

Or are all the eigenvalues of $A$ distinct?

Comment: I guess you seek the property for primitive nonnegative matrices (stronger than irreducible). The Perron Frobenius eigenvalue is then a simple extremal eigenvalue if i am not mistaken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to search for complicated counterexamples; just consider the matrix with all elements equal to 1.

[EDIT: removed a second counterexample after a comment pointed out it was reducible. If you want an example with all distinct eigenvalues, you can take the cyclic shift matrix.]

Comment: First example is correct. Second one is reducible i think

Comment: @Razor oops you are correct. Edited.